# how to sort by node attribut AgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have a DIV that can have an attribut `edth_type` and I would like to be able by an `if`to compare it's value.

I have seen in other post some guys using

```
if (string.Compare(node.Attributes["edth_type"].Value, "contenu", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
       node.Remove();
}
```

But the fact is that I need to be able to do more something like :

```
if(node.Attributes["edth_type"] != contenu)
{
   node.remove
}
```

How can I do that, I have read to msdn doc concerning `string.Compare`but did not understand it and I was wondering, since I am using HtmlAgilityPack if there was a beter way to do it.

Could someone explain the string.Compare regarding is possibility (-1, 0, 1) or know a better way to test an attribut in HtmlAgilityPack ?

Setup : ASP.NET 4.0, Code is in C# server side.

Comment: Compare is for sorting (hence the return values) - you might want to use  `string.Equals(node.Attributes["edth_type"].Value, "contenu", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` instead

Comment: @stuartd in the case I use Equals, it will return 0 or 1 for "=" or "!=" ?

Comment: Equals returns a boolean so `true` or `false` are the possible values

Comment: @stuartd okay, because in this case I need it to be "!=" but I will need it to be "=" for some other case. But is there no function in the Agility Pack to quickly compare attribute value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @stuardtd said, for this it is better to use this :

```
if (string.Equals(node.Attributes["edth_type"].Value, "contenu", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==false)
{
       node.Remove();
}
```

or like this :

```
if (!string.Equals(node.Attributes["edth_type"].Value, "contenu", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
      node.Remove();
}
```